# Java ModuleDescriptor.Builder: whats the purpose?

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system, java-16

Using [ModuleDescriptor.Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Builder.html) I can build [ModuleDescriptors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html). I can also [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html#read-java.io.InputStream-) ModuleDescriptors from files. The only thing missing now is Writing ModuleDescriptors to files.

After building my ModuleDescriptor using the builder what am I supposed to do with it?. I have gone through every class that deals with module data in the jdk. From the java.lang.module package  to all the class in the java.lang package and all these class provides me a getter method to retrieve the module descriptor but no setter method nor constructor to use moduleDescriptor as a parameter .

If there was a way to write an module descriptor to an file then the Builder class would have been of a great service as my netbeans ide seems to not be able to add version or main class info to my module. But since there is none.

What purpose does ModuleBuilder serve?

Comment: You can build a `ModuleDescriptor` and then use it to create a `ModuleReference` (by subclassing the latter). Combine that with your own implementation of `ModuleFinder` and you can create a `Configuration` / `ModuleLayer` from modules that were programmatically created. I'm not sure when or why you'd want to do that, but the functionality is there. Also, while you can set the version of a module during compilation, as far as I know you cannot do the same with the main class. It seems the main class can only be set when packaging (e.g. `jar`, `jpackage`, etc.).

Comment: Well, you could implement you own module storage. Think of, e.g. an encrypted form.

Comment: @Holger that's an interesting idea. However ModuleDescriptor is not serializable so either I can have my encrypted Descriptor only in memory.or I have to create my own wrapper classes to store the Descriptor in my own custom format which seems to much work just for a little extra security but an intriguing idea. What I am looking for is does the jdk uses this class internally for any purposes. And if it doesn't then why should we?

Comment: “implement your own module storage” meant “implement the persistent format”. It doesn’t have to be a new format, it could be the standard format, which has the same shape as a class file (it’s the `module-info.class` you can find in modular projects). There are libraries to produce class files, like ASM. This asymmetry is the same as for ordinary class files, the core API provides ways to load classes but none to generate them. That’s subject to compilers or specialized tools. And yes, the JDK uses this class, the launcher, the modular class loader, and the commands jar, jdeps, jlink, jpackage

Comment: "_What I am looking for is does the jdk uses this class internally for any purpose_" – Yes, the JDK uses the class internally. You can find one example by following the source of any of the `ModuleDescriptor#read` methods. Other examples  can be found via your IDE by searching for usages of the class.

Comment: @Holger yes you are correct the jdk does use it internally but these ideas are complicated systems which either require an external library(like ASM as u have specified)or something we should create from scratch.  I am looking for a  simpler more immediate use case such as a setModuleDescriptor() or something similar in one of the classes in the jdk where I  can see the output with no extra configuration. Or maybe the jdk made this class  public so that it can use it only for its own purposes?

Comment: As said, it’s on par with the methods for loading an ordinary class, `ClassLoader#defineClass` or `MethodHandles.Lookup#defineClass`, etc.. There is no API for creating a class file in the core API either. There are valid use cases for calling these methods, yet none for the ordinary programming tasks. Yes, for a lot of programs, these methods might be used by the JDK itself only.